# bash script for merging lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to merge multiple lines from a text file which are in between the numbers. whenever a number is encountered a new line should be created in the file.

current pattern: sample2.txt

```
1 sham  
ganesh
suresh ram
23 sam prabhu
alex
jenny
deb
```

Required pattern:

```
1 sham , ganesh, suresh ram 
23 sam prabhu , alex , jenny , deb
```

I have come up with below script

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='sample2.txt'
echo Start
   while read p; do 
     var=`echo $p | awk '{print $1}' | egrep '^[0-9]+$'`
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo $p >> file
        else
            #capture something here and append to the line
       fi
      done < $filename
```

Comment: Are the blank lines part of the input (and output), or did you just insert these for readability?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Something like this: `tr -s '\n' <file | paste -sd, | sed -E 's/,([0-9]+)/\n\1/g'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'sep&&/^[0-9]/{printf("\n");sep=""}/./{printf("%s%s",sep,$0);sep=", "}END{if(sep)printf("\n");}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `sep && /^[0-9]/ { printf("\n"); sep = ""; }` - after reading a line that starts with a digit, close the previous line (if any) by printing a newline
- `/./ { printf("%s%s", sep, $0); sep = ", "; }` - print every non-empty input line without a closing newline; precede with comma if necessary
- `END { if (sep) printf("\n"); }` - if there is any 'open' line left after all input has been read, close it by printing a newline

This approach has a low memory footprint because it does not concatenate lines in memory; every input line is printed immediately.

Sample input:

```
1 sham
ganesh
suresh ram
23 sam prabhu
alex
jenny
deb
```

Output:

```
1 sham, ganesh, suresh ram
23 sam prabhu, alex, jenny, deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]/!{/./H;z;x;s/\n/, /};x;/./p;${g;/./p}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `/^[0-9]/!{` - perform the next 4 commands only on lines that do not start with a digit
- `/./H` - if the pattern space (holding the current line) is not empty, append it to the hold space (separated by `\n`)
- `z` - clear the pattern space
- `x` - swap pattern space and hold space (resulting in an empty hold space)
- `s/\n/, /` - replace the separating `\n` by a comma
- `}` - end of block; commands to follow will be performed on every line
- `x` - swap pattern space and hold space
- `/./p` - if pattern space is not empty, print it
- `${` - perform the remaining commands only on the *last* line in the file
- `g` - copy hold space to pattern space
- `/./p` - if pattern space is not empty, print it

Sample input:

```
1 sham
ganesh
suresh ram
23 sam prabhu
alex
jenny
deb
```

Output:

```
1 sham, ganesh, suresh ram
23 sam prabhu, alex, jenny, deb
```